# Why are my pictures not opening in a separate window?

Tags: javascript

Heres the Javascript code:

```
function showCard(linkTarget) {
var propertyWidth = 400;
var propertyHeight = 350;
var winLeft = (screen.width-propertyWidth)/2;
var winTop = (screen.height-propetyHeight)/2;
var winOptions = "toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no";
winOptions += ",width=" + propertyWidth;
winOptions += ",height=" + propertyHeight;
winOptions += ",left=" + winLeft;
winOptions += ",winTop=" + winTop;
cardWindow = window.open(link.target,"cardInfo", winOptions);
cardWindow.focus();
}
var cardWindow;
```

href="valentine.jpg" onclick="showCard('valentine.jpg');return false">Valentine's Day

(I removed the tags because the code is not showing up with them)

Comment: I assume this is a typo? "linkTarget" vs. "link.target"

Answer (score 0):

`window.open(link.target...)` should be `window.open(linkTarget...)`

This is causing an error, so the `return false;` is never reached and the link navigates as normal.

Comment: so what should i do to make the pictures open in a separate window?

Comment: sorry, i edited it. the pics still dont open in a separate window :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your problem is here:

Your function is declared as:

```
   function showCard(linkTarget)
```

but you refer to the parameter passed in later in the code *with a dot* as

```
   cardWindow = window.open(link.target,"cardInfo",winOptions);
```

Comment: so what should i do to make the pictures open in a separate window?